# Error when compiling the Minko engine SDK for HTML 5

Tags: c++, html, batch-file, animation, minko

I have followed all steps mentioned in [Compiling the SDK for HTML5](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_HTML5.md) to compile the Minko framework to HTML5.

When I run the batch file `build_html5.bat`, the error

> mingw32-make is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

appears. I can see a Makefile for each of the examples.

What causes this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You *have* installed [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), and made sure its `bin` directory is in your path?

Comment: Works!!! error gone :) Thanks a lot @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) must be installed on Windows for Minko to compile to HTML5.

Make sure `mingw32-make` is available in your PATH.